# How to make a ListView<ImageView> not take more space than it needs?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I made a `ListView<ImageView>` with some image

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Image img = new Image("main/img.png");
        ObservableList<ImageView> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            ImageView iView = new ImageView(img);
            list.add(iView);
        }

        ListView<ImageView> listView = new ListView<>(list);
        listView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

        Group root = new Group(listView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

but here is what it looks like

[image]

I want the image to cover each cell completely - no insets, no padding, no scrollbar. Just a border between them.

i wanted to bind the `heightProperty` of the list view but it's read-only. The image view also doesn't have size properties but i think it's the cell that's taking the space and not the image view.

I also tried to add a `Pane` like this:

```
Image img = new Image("main/img.png");
ObservableList<Pane> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ImageView iView = new ImageView(img);
    Pane pane = new BorderPane(iView);
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
    list.add(pane);
}

ListView<Pane> listView = new ListView<>(list);
listView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
```

which gives this result

[image]

and also a renderer

```
list.setCellFactory((ListView<ImageView> l) -> new FitCell());
```

but you can't bind the cell's properties either. How do i do this without setting the height and width manually?

Comment: Why do you need a `ListView`? This doesn't really sound like the right control given the list of things you *don't* want. It is pretty much always a mistake to make the data type of a `ListView` a node subclass (such as `ImageView` or `Pane`).

Comment: @James_D I want a row of images which can be longer than the space given to it so i need it to be scrollable through clicking on one of the images and dragging it sideways (so no scrollbar to appear). didn't know that listview wasn't the right approach.

Comment: Why not put them in a `HBox` and wrap it in a `ScrollPane`? Make the scroll pane pannable, and set scroll bar policy to `NEVER`.

Comment: @James_D Why not is because i thought what i'm doing made sense xD i will definitely try what you suggested.

Comment: @James_D thanks, do you mind taking a look at another question which no one answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048335/how-to-select-a-2d-node-in-a-3d-scene

Comment: I have no experience with 3D in JavaFX....

Comment: @James_D ok, i understand, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really sound like you want a `ListView` at all. Put the `ImageView`s in a `HBox`, and wrap the `HBox` in a `ScrollPane`. You can make the scroll pane pannable and set the scroll bar policy as needed. This gives you full control over the layout, etc, without having to worry about the complexity of virtualized cells.

E.g.

```
HBox hbox = new HBox();
Image img = new Image("main/img.png");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ImageView iView = new ImageView(img);
    Pane pane = new StackPane(iView);
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
    hbox.getChildren().add(pane);
}

ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(hbox);
scroller.setPannable(true);
scroller.setFitToHeight(true);
scroller.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);

Group root = new Group(scroller);

// ...
```

You might need to set other styles on the pane, e.g. padding and borders, etc, but this should give you enough to get what you want.

Comment: Do i really need the panes to hold the imageviews in this case?

Comment: @Mark It depends. The panes have style settings that aren't available for `ImageView`, so probably. But experiment and see what works for your exact requirements.

Comment: yes i understand. Another thing: The compiler tells me that `setFitHeight` is not defined for `ScrollPane`.