# JavaFX - Adding a (3D) Scene with a camera to a Tab of a TabPane

Tags: java, javafx, scene, tabpanel, perspectivecamera

I have a JavaFX GUI set up which mainly holds a TabPane with different tabs. Usually I would create my tab like this:

```
// creating a new tab
Tab modelTab = new Tab("3D-Model");
modelTab.setClosable(false);

    // adding a BorderPane plus some sample text to the tab
    BorderPane modelTabContent = new BorderPane();
    modelTabContent.setCenter(modelTabText);

//  adding the BorderPane to the tab
modelTab.setContent(modelTabContent);
```

(I am stuffing the BorderPane inside the Tab since it streches out across the whole tab and it also centers the added content nicely.)

Now one of the tabs is supposed to show a 3D object, therefore I will need to set up a camera inside of that tab. But how can I achieve this?

My main problem is, that - if I correctly understood the oracle 3D-tutorial - I will need to set up a new (sub)scene for the perspective camera. But all of my attempts to setup a new (sub)scene and adding it to the tab have failed so far. maybe someone could give me a few hints on how to do so.

Comment: A SubScene usage sample is in the answer to [How to create custom 3d model in JavaFX 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8).  Try adapting it to your use case.