# How to create hollow cylinder and truncated cone with JavaFX?

Tags: math, javafx, 3d, geometry

I'm learning JavaFX 3D. So far I have not found a way how I can create the following objects:

- Hollow cylinder
- Truncated cone

Can someone please give me a short code example?

Any help will be appreciated. :-)

Comment: I stand at the beginning of JavaFX, i have several 3D Examples viewed and tried in Netbeans. My question is how a TriangleMesh for the two objects can be calculated?

Comment: Well, you could [download a cylinder model from thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:35331/#files) and load it up with an [interactive mesh importer](http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html).  But maybe you don't want a pre-generated model, maybe you actually want to implement an algorithm to generate a triangle mesh for your shapes in code, in which case I would recommend you attempt to solve the problem yourself and post your sample code if you run into issues.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8.

Comment: "...want to implement an algorithm to generate a triangle mesh for your shapes in code.." - Yes, you´r right, and therefore i´m searching for a sample code to calc a hollow cylinder, for the first step.

Comment: Maybe review some of the code and algorithms used for [shape generation](https://github.com/Birdasaur/FXyz/blob/master/src/org/fxyz/shapes/primitives/ConeMesh.java) by the [F(X)xyz project](http://birdasaur.github.io/FXyz/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question but I've been trying to solve similar problem so here is my solution for truncated cone:

```
public class Cone extends Group{

int rounds = 360;
int r1 = 100;
int r2 = 50;
int h = 100;

public Cone() {
    Group cone = new Group();
    PhongMaterial material = new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE);

    float[] points = new float[rounds *12];
    float[] textCoords = {
            0.5f, 0,
            0, 1,
            1, 1
    };
    int[] faces = new int[rounds *12];

    for(int i= 0; i<rounds; i++){
        int index = i*12;
        //0
        points[index] = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i))*r2;
        points[index+1] = (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i))*r2;
        points[index+2] = h/2;
        //1
        points[index+3] = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i))*r1;
        points[index+4] = (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i))*r1;
        points[index+5] = -h/2;
        //2
        points[index+6] = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i+1))*r1;
        points[index+7] = (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i+1))*r1;
        points[index+8] = -h/2;
        //3
        points[index+9] = (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i+1))*r2;
        points[index+10] = (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i+1))*r2;
        points[index+11] = h/2;        
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<rounds ; i++){
        int index = i*12;
        faces[index]=i*4;
        faces[index+1]=0;
        faces[index+2]=i*4+1;
        faces[index+3]=1;
        faces[index+4]=i*4+2;
        faces[index+5]=2;

        faces[index+6]=i*4;
        faces[index+7]=0;
        faces[index+8]=i*4+2;
        faces[index+9]=1;
        faces[index+10]=i*4+3;
        faces[index+11]=2;
    }

    TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();
    mesh.getPoints().addAll(points);
    mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(textCoords);
    mesh.getFaces().addAll(faces);

    Cylinder circle1 = new Cylinder(r1, 0.1);
    circle1.setMaterial(material);
    circle1.setTranslateZ( -h / 2);
    circle1.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
    circle1.setRotate(90);

    Cylinder circle2 = new Cylinder(r2, 0.1);
    circle2.setMaterial(material);
    circle2.setTranslateZ( h / 2);
    circle2.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
    circle2.setRotate(90);


     MeshView meshView = new MeshView();
    meshView.setMesh(mesh);
    meshView.setMaterial(material);
    //meshView.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);
    cone.getChildren().addAll(meshView);
    Rotate r1 = new Rotate(90, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    cone.getTransforms().add(r1);
    getChildren().addAll(cone);
}
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I started using the code supplied in an other answer on this page, but I wanted to make it as a single mesh without the cylinders in the ends. I also calculated better texture coordinates and normals. (I use Vecmath for the normal calculation. This should probably be changed to Apache commons math or something more modern...)

```
 /**
 * Create a cone shape. Origin is center of base (bottom circle). Height is along the Y axis
 * @param m A given TirangleMesh
 * @param res The resolution of the circles
 * @param radius The base radius
 * @param topRadius The top radius. If this is > 0 the cone is capped
 * @param height The height of the cone along the Y axis
 * @param texture The texture
 */
public static void createCone(TriangleMesh m, int res, float radius, float topRadius, float height, TextureMapping texture)
{
  if (texture == null)
    texture = defaultTextureMapping;

  m.setVertexFormat(VertexFormat.POINT_NORMAL_TEXCOORD);
      
  float[] v = new float[res * 6]; //vertices
  float[] n = new float[(res+2)*3]; //face normals
  float[] uv = new float[(res * 8) + 4]; //texture coordinates
  int[] f = new int[18*(2*res-2)]; // faces ((divisions * 18) + ((divisions-2)*18))
  
  float radPerDiv = ((float)Math.PI * 2f) / res;
  
  int tv = res * 3; //top plane vertices start index
  int tuv = (res+1) * 2; //top plane uv start index
  int bcuv = tuv * 2;//(res * 4) + 4; //bottom cap uv start index
  int tcuv = bcuv + (res * 2); //bottom cap uv start index
  for(int i = 0; i < res; i++)
  {
    int vi = i*3;  
    float cos = (float) Math.cos(radPerDiv*(i));
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(radPerDiv*(i));
    //bottom plane vertices
    v[vi] = cos * radius; //X
    v[vi + 1] = 0; //Y
    v[vi + 2] = sin * radius; //Z
    
    //top plane vertices
    v[tv + vi] = cos * topRadius; //X
    v[tv + vi + 1] = height; //Y
    v[tv + vi + 2] = sin * topRadius; //Z
    
    int uvi = i*2;
    //texture coordinate side down
    uv[uvi] = 1f-((float)i/(float)res);
    uv[uvi + 1] = 1f;
    
    //texture coordinate side up
    uv[tuv + uvi] = uv[uvi];
    uv[tuv + uvi + 1] = 0;
    
    //texture coordinate bottom cap
    uv[bcuv + uvi] = (1f+cos)/2f;
    uv[bcuv + uvi + 1] = (1f+sin)/2f;
    
    //texture coordinate top cap
    uv[tcuv + uvi] = (1f-cos)/2f;
    uv[tcuv + uvi + 1] = (1f+sin)/2f;
    
    //face normals
    if(i>0)
    {
      Vector3f p0 = new Vector3f(v[vi - 3], v[vi - 2], v[vi - 1]);
      Vector3f p1 = new Vector3f(v[vi], v[vi + 1], v[vi + 2]);
      Vector3f p2 = new Vector3f(v[tv + vi], v[tv + vi + 1], v[tv + vi + 2]);
      p1.sub(p0);
      p2.sub(p0);
      p0.cross(p2, p1);
      p0.normalize();
      n[vi - 3] = p0.x;
      n[vi - 2] = p0.y;
      n[vi - 1] = p0.z;
    }
    if(i==res-1)
    {
      Vector3f p0 = new Vector3f(v[vi], v[vi + 1], v[vi + 2]);
      Vector3f p1 = new Vector3f(v[0], v[1], v[2]);
      Vector3f p2 = new Vector3f(v[tv], v[tv + 1], v[tv + 2]);
      p1.sub(p0);
      p2.sub(p0);
      p0.cross(p2, p1);
      p0.normalize();
      n[vi] = p0.x;
      n[vi + 1] = p0.y;
      n[vi + 2] = p0.z;
    }
    
    //faces around
    int fi = i*18; 
    //first triangle of face
    f[fi] = i; //vertex
    f[fi+1] = i; //normal
    f[fi+2] = i; //uv
    
    f[fi+3] = res+i; //vertex
    f[fi+4] = i; //normal
    f[fi+5] = res+1+i; //uv
    
    f[fi+6] = i+1; //vertex
    f[fi+7] = i+1; //normal
    f[fi+8] = i+1; //uv
    
    //second triangle of face 
    f[fi+9] = i+1; //vertex
    f[fi+10] = i+1; //normal
    f[fi+11] = i+1; //uv
    
    f[fi+12] = res+i; //vertex
    f[fi+13] = i; //normal
    f[fi+14] = res+1+i; //uv
    
    f[fi+15] = res+i+1; //vertex
    f[fi+16] = i+1; //normal
    f[fi+17] = res+2+i; //uv
    
    //wrap around, use the first vertices/normals
    if(i==res-1)
    {
      f[fi+6] = 0; //vertex
      f[fi+9] = 0; //vertex
      f[fi+15] = res; //vertex
      
      f[fi+7] = 0; //normal
      f[fi+10] = 0; //normal
      f[fi+16] = 0; //normal
    }
    
    //top and bottom caps
    int fi2 = (i*9)+(res*18); //start index for bottom cap. Start after cone side is done
    int fi3 = fi2 + (res*9) - 18; //fi2 + ((divisions - 2) * 9) //start index for top cap. Start after the bottom cap is done 
    int uv2 = (res*2)+2; //start index of bottom cap texture coordinate 
    int uv3 = (res*3)+2; //start index of top cap texture coordinate 
    if(i<res-2)
    {
      //bottom cap
      f[fi2] = 0;
      f[fi2+1] = res; //normal
      f[fi2+2] = uv2; //uv
      
      f[fi2+3] = i+1;
      f[fi2+4] = res; //normal
      f[fi2+5] = uv2 + i+1; //uv
      
      f[fi2+6] = i+2;
      f[fi2+7] = res; //normal
      f[fi2+8] = uv2 + i+2; //uv
      
      //top cap
      f[fi3] = res;
      f[fi3+1] = res + 1; //normal
      f[fi3+2] = uv3; //uv
      
      f[fi3+3] = res+i+2;
      f[fi3+4] = res + 1; //normal
      f[fi3+5] = uv3  + i+2; //uv
      
      f[fi3+6] = res+i+1;
      f[fi3+7] = res + 1; //normal
      f[fi3+8] = uv3  + i+1; //uv
    }
  }
  
  //smooth normals
  float[] ns = new float[n.length];
  Vector3f n0 = new Vector3f();
  Vector3f n1 = new Vector3f();
  for(int i = 0; i < res; i++)
  {
    int p0 = i*3;
    int p1 = (i-1)*3;
    if(i==0)
      p1 = (res-1)*3;    
    n0.set(n[p0], n[p0+1], n[p0+2]);
    n1.set(n[p1], n[p1+1], n[p1+2]);
    n0.add(n1);
    n0.normalize();
    
    ns[p0] = n0.x;
    ns[p0+1] = n0.y;
    ns[p0+2] = n0.z;
  }
  
  int ni = res * 3;
  ns[ni + 1] = -1; //bottom cap normal Y axis
  ns[ni + 4] = 1; //top cap normal Y axis
  
  uv[tuv-1] = 1; //bottom ring end uv coordinate
  
  //set all data to mesh
  m.getPoints().setAll(v);
  m.getNormals().setAll(ns);
  m.getTexCoords().setAll(uv);
  m.getFaces().setAll(f);
}
```

**Edit:**
And here is code for a hollow cone (or cylinder, just set both rads to same value) Here I am using JavaFX vectors in stead of Vecmath

```
/**
 * Create a hollow cone shape. Origin is center of base (bottom circle). Height is along the Y axis
 * @param m A given TirangleMesh
 * @param res The resolution of the circles
 * @param radius The base radius
 * @param topRadius The top radius. If this is > 0 the cone is capped
 * @param height The height of the cone along the Y axis
 * @param thickness The thickness of the cone wall
 * @param center If the origo shall be in the center, False
 * @param texture The texture
 */
public static void createHollowCone(TriangleMesh m, int res, float radius, float topRadius, float height, float thickness, boolean center, TextureMapping texture)
{
  if (texture == null)
    texture = defaultTextureMapping;
  
  m.setVertexFormat(VertexFormat.POINT_NORMAL_TEXCOORD);

  float[] v = new float[res * 12]; //vertices
  float[] n = new float[res*3]; //face normals (raw)
  float[] uv = new float[(res * 24) + 8]; //texture coordinates
  int[] f = new int[res*72]; // faces 
  
  float radPerDiv = ((float)Math.PI * 2f) / res;
  float buvf = 1-(thickness/radius);
  float tuvf = 1-(thickness/topRadius);
  
  int otcvsi = res * 3; //outside top circle vertices start index
  int ibcvsi = res * 6; //inside bottom circle vertices start index
  int itcvsi = res * 9; //inside top circle vertices start index
  
  int ifsi = res*18; //inside faces start index
  int bfsi = res*36; //bottom faces start index
  int tfsi = res*54; //bottom faces start index
  
  int tuvsi = (res+1) * 2; //top plane uv start index
  int bcuvsi = tuvsi * 2;//(res * 4) + 4; //bottom cap uv start index
  int tcuvsi = bcuvsi + (res * 4); //bottom cap uv start index
  
  int bcfuvsi = bcuvsi/2; //bottom cap faces uv start index
  int tcfuvsi = tcuvsi/2; //top cap faces uv start index
  for(int i = 0; i < res; i++)
  {
    int vi = i*3;  
    float cos = (float) Math.cos(radPerDiv*(i));
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(radPerDiv*(i));
    
    //outside bottom circle vertices
    v[vi] = cos * radius; //X
    v[vi + 1] = center?-height/2f:0; //Y
    v[vi + 2] = sin * radius; //Z
    
    //outside top circle vertices
    v[otcvsi + vi] = cos * topRadius; //X
    v[otcvsi + vi + 1] = center?height/2f:height; //Y
    v[otcvsi + vi + 2] = sin * topRadius; //Z
    
    //inside bottom circle vertices
    v[ibcvsi + vi] = cos * (radius-thickness); //X
    v[ibcvsi + vi + 1] = center?-height/2f:0; //Y
    v[ibcvsi + vi + 2] = sin * (radius-thickness); //Z
    
    //inside top circle vertices
    v[itcvsi + vi] = cos * (topRadius-thickness); //X
    v[itcvsi + vi + 1] = center?height/2f:height; //Y
    v[itcvsi + vi + 2] = sin * (topRadius-thickness); //Z
    
    
    int uvi = i*2;
    //texture coordinate outer side down
    uv[uvi] = 1f-((float)i/(float)res);
    uv[uvi + 1] = 1f;
    
    //texture coordinate outer side up
    uv[tuvsi + uvi] = uv[uvi];
    uv[tuvsi + uvi + 1] = 0;
    
    //texture coordinate bottom
    uv[bcuvsi + uvi] = (1f+cos)/2f;
    uv[bcuvsi + uvi + 1] = (1f-sin)/2f;
     
    uv[(res*2)+bcuvsi + uvi] = (1f+(cos*buvf))/2f;
    uv[(res*2)+bcuvsi + uvi + 1] = (1f-(sin*buvf))/2f;
    
    //texture coordinate top cap
    uv[tcuvsi + uvi] = (1f+cos)/2f;
    uv[tcuvsi + uvi + 1] = (1f+sin)/2f;
    
    uv[(res*2)+tcuvsi + uvi] = (1f+(cos*tuvf))/2f;
    uv[(res*2)+tcuvsi + uvi + 1] = (1f+(sin*tuvf))/2f;      
    //face normals
    if(i>0)
    {
      Point3D p0 = new Point3D(v[vi - 3], v[vi - 2], v[vi - 1]);
      Point3D p1 = new Point3D(v[vi], v[vi + 1], v[vi + 2]);
      Point3D p2 = new Point3D(v[otcvsi + vi], v[otcvsi + vi + 1], v[otcvsi + vi + 2]);
      p1 = p1.subtract(p0);
      p2 = p2.subtract(p0);
      p0 = p2.crossProduct(p1);
      p0 = p0.normalize();
      n[vi - 3] = (float)p0.getX();
      n[vi - 2] = (float)p0.getY();
      n[vi - 1] = (float)p0.getZ();
    }
    if(i==res-1)
    {
      Point3D p0 = new Point3D(v[vi], v[vi + 1], v[vi + 2]);
      Point3D p1 = new Point3D(v[0], v[1], v[2]);
      Point3D p2 = new Point3D(v[otcvsi], v[otcvsi + 1], v[otcvsi + 2]);
      p1 = p1.subtract(p0);
      p2 = p2.subtract(p0);
      p0 = p2.crossProduct(p1);
      p0 = p0.normalize();
      n[vi] = (float)p0.getX();
      n[vi + 1] = (float)p0.getY();
      n[vi + 2] = (float)p0.getZ();
    }
   
    int fi = i*18; 
    //faces around outside
    
    //first triangle of face
    f[fi] = i; //vertex
    f[fi+1] = i; //normal
    f[fi+2] = i; //uv
    
    f[fi+3] = res+i; //vertex
    f[fi+4] = i; //normal
    f[fi+5] = res+1+i; //uv
    
    f[fi+6] = i+1; //vertex
    f[fi+7] = i+1; //normal
    f[fi+8] = i+1; //uv
    
    //second triangle of face 
    f[fi+9] = i+1; //vertex
    f[fi+10] = i+1; //normal
    f[fi+11] = i+1; //uv
    
    f[fi+12] = res+i; //vertex
    f[fi+13] = i; //normal
    f[fi+14] = res+1+i; //uv
    
    f[fi+15] = res+i+1; //vertex
    f[fi+16] = i+1; //normal
    f[fi+17] = res+2+i; //uv
    
    //faces around inside
    //first triangle of face
    f[ifsi+fi] = (res*2)+i; //vertex
    f[ifsi+fi+1] = res+i; //normal
    f[ifsi+fi+2] = res-i; //uv
    
    f[ifsi+fi+3] = (res*2)+i+1; //vertex
    f[ifsi+fi+4] = res+i+1; //normal
    f[ifsi+fi+5] = res-1-i; //uv
    
    f[ifsi+fi+6] = (res*3)+i; //vertex
    f[ifsi+fi+7] = res+i; //normal
    f[ifsi+fi+8] = res+res+1-i; //uv
    
    //second triangle of face 
    f[ifsi+fi+9] = (res*2)+i+1; //vertex
    f[ifsi+fi+10] = res+i+1; //normal
    f[ifsi+fi+11] = res-1-i; //uv
    
    f[ifsi+fi+12] = (res*3)+i+1; //vertex
    f[ifsi+fi+13] = res+i+1; //normal
    f[ifsi+fi+14] = res+res-i; //uv
    
    f[ifsi+fi+15] = (res*3)+i; //vertex
    f[ifsi+fi+16] = res+i; //normal
    f[ifsi+fi+17] = res+res+1-i; //uv
    
    //faces on bottom
    //first triangle of face

    f[bfsi+fi] = i; //vertex 0
    f[bfsi+fi+1] = res*2; //normal
    f[bfsi+fi+2] = bcfuvsi+i; //uv
    
    f[bfsi+fi+3] = i+1; //vertex 1
    f[bfsi+fi+4] = res*2; //normal
    f[bfsi+fi+5] = bcfuvsi+i+1; //uv
    
    f[bfsi+fi+6] = (res*2)+i+1; //vertex n+1
    f[bfsi+fi+7] = res*2; //normal
    f[bfsi+fi+8] = bcfuvsi+res+i+1; //uv
    
    
    //second triangle of face 
    f[bfsi+fi+9] = (res*2)+i+1; //vertex n+1
    f[bfsi+fi+10] = res*2; //normal
    f[bfsi+fi+11] = bcfuvsi+res+i+1; //uv
    
    f[bfsi+fi+12] = (res*2)+i; //vertex n
    f[bfsi+fi+13] = res*2; //normal
    f[bfsi+fi+14] = bcfuvsi+res+i; //uv
    
    f[bfsi+fi+15] = i; //vertex 0
    f[bfsi+fi+16] = res*2; //normal
    f[bfsi+fi+17] = bcfuvsi+i; //uv
    
    //faces on top
    //first triangle of face
    f[tfsi+fi] = res+i; //vertex 0
    f[tfsi+fi+1] = res*2+1; //normal
    f[tfsi+fi+2] = tcfuvsi+i; //uv
    
    f[tfsi+fi+3] = (res*3)+i; //vertex n
    f[tfsi+fi+4] = res*2+1; //normal
    f[tfsi+fi+5] = tcfuvsi+res+i; //uv
    
    f[tfsi+fi+6] = (res*3)+i+1; //vertex n+1
    f[tfsi+fi+7] = res*2+1; //normal
    f[tfsi+fi+8] = tcfuvsi+res+i+1; //uv
    
    //second triangle of face 
    f[tfsi+fi+9] = (res*3)+i+1; //vertex n+1
    f[tfsi+fi+10] = res*2+1; //normal
    f[tfsi+fi+11] = tcfuvsi+res+i+1; //uv
    
    f[tfsi+fi+12] = res+i+1; //vertex 1
    f[tfsi+fi+13] = res*2+1; //normal
    f[tfsi+fi+14] = tcfuvsi+i+1; //uv
    
    f[tfsi+fi+15] = res+i; //vertex 0
    f[tfsi+fi+16] = res*2+1; //normal
    f[tfsi+fi+17] = tcfuvsi+i; //uv
    
    //wrap around, use the first vertices/normals
    if(i==res-1)
    {
      f[fi+6] = 0; //vertex
      f[fi+9] = 0; //vertex
      f[fi+15] = res; //vertex
      
      f[ifsi+fi+3] = res*2; //vertex
      f[ifsi+fi+9] = res*2; //vertex
      f[ifsi+fi+12] = res*3; //vertex
      
      f[bfsi+fi+3] = 0; //vertex
      f[bfsi+fi+6] = res*2; //vertex
      f[bfsi+fi+9] = res*2; //vertex
      
      f[tfsi+fi+6] = res*3; //vertex
      f[tfsi+fi+9] = res*3; //vertex
      f[tfsi+fi+12] = res; //vertex
      
      
      f[fi+7] = 0; //normal
      f[fi+10] = 0; //normal
      f[fi+16] = 0; //normal
      
      f[ifsi+fi+4] = res; //normal
      f[ifsi+fi+10] = res; //normal
      f[ifsi+fi+13] = res; //normal
      
      
      f[bfsi+fi+5] = bcfuvsi; //uv
      f[bfsi+fi+8] = bcfuvsi+res; //uv
      f[bfsi+fi+11] = bcfuvsi+res; //uv
      
      f[tfsi+fi+8] = tcfuvsi+res; //uv
      f[tfsi+fi+11] = tcfuvsi+res; //uv
      f[tfsi+fi+14] = tcfuvsi; //uv
      
      
    }
    
    
  }
  
  //smooth normals
  float[] ns = new float[(n.length*2)+6];
  int ni = res * 3;
  for(int i = 0; i < res; i++)
  {
    int p0 = i*3;
    int p1 = (i-1)*3;
    if(i==0)
      p1 = (res-1)*3;    
    Point3D n0 = new Point3D(n[p0], n[p0+1], n[p0+2]);
    Point3D n1 = new Point3D(n[p1], n[p1+1], n[p1+2]);
    n0 = n0.add(n1);
    n0 = n0.normalize();

    ns[p0] = (float)n0.getX();
    ns[p0+1] = (float)n0.getY();
    ns[p0+2] = (float)n0.getZ();
    
    n0 = n0.multiply(-1);
    ns[ni+p0] = (float)n0.getX();
    ns[ni+p0+1] = (float)n0.getY();
    ns[ni+p0+2] = (float)n0.getZ();

  }
  
  ni = res * 6;
  ns[ni + 1] = -1; //bottom cap normal Y axis
  ns[ni + 4] = 1; //top cap normal Y axis
  
  uv[tuvsi-1] = 1; //bottom ring end uv coordinate
  
  
  //set all data to mesh
  m.getPoints().setAll(v);
  m.getNormals().setAll(ns);
  m.getTexCoords().setAll(uv);
  m.getFaces().setAll(f);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The first - create a cylinder, and use two different appearance objects - one for cylinder, side, and one for the two bases. For the two bases, use an invisible appearance (rendering attributes). For info on how to set different appearances to bases, set thread:
 http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=663825&tstart=0

The second - use a clipping plane to clip of the bottom and top of the cylinder, and you have a hollow cylinder.

Those two methods will give you a hollow cylinder with a COMPLETELY empty interior.

If you're looking to have walls with a given thickness, there is a boolean operations set available on the internet. Create a large cylinder, and subtract a smaller cylinder. For info on the boolean op set, set this thread: http://forum.java.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=658612&tstart=0

Finally, it's really pretty easy to create a cylinder's geometry yourself, and it can be automated really easily with a loop. I would create four separate geometries: one for the inner cylinder with the rendered faces on the inside, one for the outer cylinder, with the rendered faces on the outside, one for the base, a disc with a hole in the middle and bottom surfaces rendered, and one for the top, another disc with a hole in the middle, and top surfaces rendered.

That can all be done pretty easily with a triangle strip array.