# Create hollow cylinder with java3d

Tags: java, java-3d

In `java.awt.Frame` I created a cylinder :

```
Cylinder cyl1 = new Cylinder(1.0f, 2.0f, app);
```

How to create a hollow cylinder from this cyl1 ?

Comment: See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392456/how-to-create-hollow-cylinder-and-truncated-cone-with-javafx

Comment: it seems not working, I am making software with Swing.

Comment: can anyone help me