# JavaFX normals VertexFormat

Tags: java, algorithm, vector, javafx, normals

I was fiddling around with JavaFX and loaded a model and found out…  not all faces are flipped correct because they turn out black.

So I started looking how to add normals to the model and found out about VertexFormat, but it can't be instantiated. Some thorough search on the internet didn't wield any answers on how to implement it and some messages referred it as something for future releases of JavaFX.

I understand its a matter of how the triangles are written… clockwise or counterclockwise. So anybody can give me a clue, how to write an algorithm that tells me when I should reverse the triangle creation? Or just how to bypass the whole problem?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I flipped all the triangles of which normal vector is negative... The expected outcome was that every face would be rendered but instead even less showed up.

EDIT:

Link to triangleMesh:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html

Link to VertexFormat (used by triangleMesh according to doc):
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/VertexFormat.html

SOLUTION:

1. quick and dirty: add the array of indices (referring to the points / making up triangles) again but then reversed. So the face loop of every triangle is drawn twice… cw and ccw.
2. compare the normal vector of the face with javafx to the one that is parsed from the obj file.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: the first answer within this question provides a mcve. the arrays as presented in the question show the effect of drawing a triangle clockwise or counterclockwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8

Comment: Yes, but what is your question and problem?  How would somebody answer it?  The linked example doesn't reference VertexFormat.  Different functionality for clockwise vs counterclockwise definition order for triangles, is [how JavaFX works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html): "A triangle has a front and back face. The winding order of a triangle's vertices determines which side is the front face. JavaFX chooses the counter-clockwise (or right-hand rule) winding order as the front face. By default, only the front face of a triangle is rendered."

Comment: Yes indeed. How do you determine if a triangle is drawn cw or ccw by its normal vector in 3d space