# how do i display a 3d shape on button click in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, fxml

for a personal project of mine for my programming class and to be released later i came to a problem that i wasn't expecting to come across. i was wanting to display a 3d shape in a pane when a menu-button item is clicked, i went searching over the internet searching it 50-100 different ways(or a good rough estimate) and haven't found anything on it. I've been baffled on how to display 3d shapes when a menu-item is clicked, here's my source code(fxml):

```
<MenuButton layoutX="14.0" layoutY="92.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="shapes">
     <items>
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#itemcircle" text="circle" />
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#itemsquare" text="square/surfice" />
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#itemcube" text="cube" />
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#itemsphere" text="sphere" />
        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#itemcyllinder" text="cyllinder" />
     </items>
  </MenuButton>
```

my other source code sample(javaFX):

```
public void itemcyllinder(ActionEvent cyllinderspawn)
{
    Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(40, 120);
    cylinder.setTranslateX(500);
    cylinder.setTranslateY(-25);
    cylinder.setTranslateZ(600);
}
```

so how do i display 3d shapes/objects using javafx/fxml?

**EDIT**: i forgot to mention i want it displayed into a pane on my scene

Comment: Have you tried adding an click event handler on the button and changing the visibility of the `Cylinder` on click?

Comment: no but ill try.

Comment: Perhaps look at the [model viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8) defined in the answer to "How to create custom 3d model in JavaFX 8?"  It's not exactly what you are asking for but might give some ideas on how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer this is all i needed to do with the cylinder:

```
public void itemcyllinder(ActionEvent cyllinderspawn)
{
    Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(40, 120);
    cylinder.setTranslateX(368.0);
    cylinder.setTranslateY(311.0);
    whereitgoes.getChildren().add(cylinder);
}
```

i called my pane whereitgoes and then i just used the getChildren to have the cylinder display in the pane i called where it goes with a menu button item click(sorry i can't give a picture example)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I would try to create a 3D scene on a [SubScene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html), and set that as the [graphic property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#graphicProperty) of the menu item.

*Edit:* thought you wanted to set the 3D scene as a graphic of a menu item. Anyway to mix 2D and 3D you need to create SubScenes.

Comment: could you elaborate on that more maybe an example code?