# How to get face coordinates?

Tags: java, javafx, java-3d

On the topic of creating custom 3D models, I found this answer. It remains incomprehensible to me how the coordinates of the texture and points mix.
Here's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8).
If this is some kind of global concept, and not a feature of building 3D in Java, then I will be glad to mention any literature where these things are well covered. For convenience, I give an example of a code where getting the coordinates of the faces is covered with darkness for me. Thank!

```
float[] points =
{  
    50, 0, 0,  // v0 (iv0 = 0)
    45, 10, 0, // v1 (iv1 = 1)
    55, 10, 0  // v2 (iv2 = 2)
};
float[] texCoords =
{  
    0.5f, 0.5f, // t0 (it0 = 0)
    0.0f, 1.0f, // t1 (it1 = 1)
    1.0f, 1.0f  // t2 (it2 = 2)
};
int[] faces =
{
    0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, // iv0, it0, iv2, it2, iv1, it1 (front face)
    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2  // iv0, it0, iv1, it1, iv2, it2 back face
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the literature with the answers. If anyone is interested, here is the link.[a link](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Wb8ICAAAQBAJ&pg=PA832&lpg=PA832&dq=float%5B%5D+points+%3D%7B50,+0,+0,++//+v0+(iv0+%3D+0)45,+10,+0,+//+v1+(iv1+%3D+1)55,+10,+0++//+v2+(iv2+%3D+2)%7D;&source=bl&ots=_9fHOJhYZ1&sig=ACfU3U0QGCqTvA3bwdElQq9dTjo8nq25Dw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj73pzs9P7fAhWJOSwKHbiMD0UQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=float%5B%5D%20points%20%3D%7B50%2C%200%2C%200%2C%20%20%2F%2F%20v0%20(iv0%20%3D%200)45%2C%2010%2C%200%2C%20%2F%2F%20v1%20(iv1%20%3D%201)55%2C%2010%2C%200%20%20%2F%2F%20v2%20(iv2%20%3D%202)%7D%3B&f=false)

Comment: This is a very common concept in the 3D graphics world. It is not specific to JavaFX.

Comment: @mipa I read about it and now formed my presentation. Just before that, I did not come across 3D.

Comment: @mipa I still have this question. Perhaps the answer is obvious. But, I find it difficult. In particular, searching Google for method names did not help me. Could you tell me which way I should look? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276511/where-the-author-of-the-code-takes-the-name-of-the-mesh)

Comment: Maybe this wikipedia page is helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh#Face-vertex_meshes

Comment: @mipa With this topic I figured out and did what I wanted. I'm talking about the question that I pointed out in the link. There the author of the code gets the constituent models by some names.

Comment: @mipa [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276511/where-the-author-of-the-code-takes-the-name-of-the-mesh)

Comment: @mipa Sorry for my low English.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. I haven't used this model importer you are referring to.

Comment: @mipa I understand that it is better not to use those technologies that few people use. Could you tell me which importer is better to use, so that he has a large community, which could in the case of a question suggest how to work with him?

Comment: Oh, you misunderstood me. I don't use any model importers because in the scenarios where I use JavaFX 3D I programmatically create the faces and so don't have a need for any importers. I only know the importers from http://www.interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html but haven't used them.

Comment: @mipa Now I understand everything)) Well, thanks for the answers! I will torment the stackoverflow community)))