# How to change between wireframe and solid in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

3d software allow  user to change draw mode dinamically. It can be implemented on javafx ?

Comment: There is an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8).

Comment: thanks @jewelsea  , CheckBox approach . Good idea 'cause drawmode has 2 options .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Changing draw mode with radio buttons**

[image: drawmode javafx]

In this approach a [`Box`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Box.html) instance change its [`DrawMode`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/DrawMode.html) with radiobuttons.

This is a single class javafx you can try .

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        var perspective = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
        perspective.setNearClip(0.1);
        perspective.setFarClip(500);
        perspective.setTranslateZ(-150);
        
        
        
        Shape3D cube = new Box(50, 50, 50);
        cube.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);
        cube.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.CORAL));

        var toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        var solid = new RadioButton("solid");
        solid.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        solid.setSelected(true);
        var wire = new RadioButton("wireframe");
        wire.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);

        var hBox = new HBox(solid, wire);

        toggleGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((o) -> {
            Toggle selectedToggle = toggleGroup.getSelectedToggle();

            if (selectedToggle == solid) {
                cube.setDrawMode(DrawMode.FILL);
            }
            if (selectedToggle == wire) {
                cube.setDrawMode(DrawMode.LINE);

            }

        });

        var group3d = new Group(perspective, cube);

        var subscene = new SubScene(group3d, 300, 400, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        subscene.setCamera(perspective);

        var stack = new StackPane(subscene, hBox);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(stack, 300, 400));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```